# Карта Google со строкой ввода адреса

Tags: google-maps-api

Для доставки курьером товара нужно разместить карту гугл и поле ввода адреса.

При вводе адреса хотелось бы, чтобы предлагались разные (похожие) варианты и при выборе нужного, ставился бы маркер на карте.

По апи гугл мапс пробежался по диагонали, вроде не нашел.

Как подобное реализовать?

Comment: наверное это нужно https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: [Тут, вроде то что вы ищите.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?hl=ru)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но больше, я думаю, вот это - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?hl=ru